# How to handle sessions php

Tags: php, session

I can't find a fitting article for this subject. Indeed, there are a lot of those I found, but they are old. How should I store session? How can I secure them, as much as possible, etc.

Comment: why dont u google this and see the question all around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Those](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) on php.net are updated. It's very easy to use sessions, you just (before any ouput) add this snippet of code `session_start()` and then assign whatever you want to $_SESSION variable.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, don't store sessions. The `session_start()` and `$_SESSION` variable should be all you need. If you need data to persist consider using either [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or store the corresponding data in a local database which relates to a certain **registered** user.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are being used in order to "pass" data which is stored in $_SESSION variables.
The data you can store in those variables can be username that's being saved after successful log in , or another information you find important becuase you might use it more than once.

In order to start session you use the session_start() function, and in order to create a new session variable you use $_SESSION['sessionName']=$var;